# Get top 50 records for a certain value w/ mongo and meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

In my meteor project, I have a leaderboard of sorts, where it shows players of every level on a chart, spread across every level in the game. For simplicitys sake, lets say there are levels 1-100. Currently, to avoid overloading meteor, I just tell the server to send me every record newer than two weeks old, but that's not sufficient for an accurate leaderboard.

What I'm trying to do is show 50 records representing *each level*. So, if there are 100 records at level 1, 85 at level 2, 65 at level 3, and 45 at level 4, I want to show the *latest* 50 records from each level, making it so I would have [50, 50, 50, 45] records, respectively.

The data looks something like this:

```
{
    snapshotDate: new Date(),
    level: 1,
    hp: 5000,
    str: 100
}
```

I think this requires some mongodb aggregation, but I couldn't quite figure out how to do this in one query. It would be trivial to do it in two, though - select all records, group by level, sort each level by date, then take the last 50 records from each level. However, I would prefer to do it in one operation, if I could. Is it currently possible to do something like this?

Comment: Can you please post a sample document in the collection? It becomes a lot easier to provide solutions when the document structure is clearly depicted.

Comment: @BatScream I've added a small version of the document to the question.

Comment: Collection.find({level:1},{limit:50});

Comment: @Sindis I want to find the latest 50 of every level, not just one level, and not just 50 arbitrary records.

Comment: You will have to loop it then through each level (with if clause checking if there is any record) and limit it as you like(limit limits the records, if u have 45 it will print you 45, not 50)

Comment: @Sindis Yes, that sounds a lot like what I _can_ do (see my "it's trivial to do in two steps" note), but I'm trying to find a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to pick up `n` top records of a group, in the aggregation pipeline. There is an unresolved open ticket regarding this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377.

There are two solutions to this:

- Keep your document structure as it is now and aggregate, but, 
  grab the `n` top records and slice off the remaining records for each group, in the client side.

Code:

```
var top_records = [];

db.collection.aggregate([
// The sort operation needs to come before the $group,
// because once the records are grouped by level, 
// there exists only one document per group.
{$sort:{"snapshotDate":-1}},
// Maintain all the records in an array in sorted order. 
{$group:{"_id":"$level","recs":{$push:"$$ROOT"}}},
],{allowDiskUse: true}).forEach(function(level){
     level.recs.splice(50);   //Keep only the top 50 records.
     top_records.push(level);
})
```

Remember that this loads all the documents for each `level` and removes the unwanted records in the client side.

- Alter your document structure to accomplish what you really need. If
  you only need the top `n` records always, keep them always in sorted
  order in the root document.This is accomplished using a [sorted capped array](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/58782996153/push-to-sorted-array).

Your document would look like this:

```
{
 level:1,
 records:[{snapshotDate:2,hp:5000,str:100},
          {snapshotDate:1,hp:5001,str:101}]
}
```

where, `records` is an capped array of size `n` and always has sub documents sorted in descending order of their `snapshotDate`.

To make the `records` array work that way, we always perform an update operation when we need to insert documents to it for any `level`.

```
db.collection.update({"level":1},
            {$push:{
                    recs:{
                          $each:[{snapshotDate:1,hp:5000,str:100},
                                 {snapshotDate:2,hp:5001,str:101}],
                          $sort:{"snapshotDate":-1},
                          $slice:50 //Always trim the array size to 50.
                         }
            }},{upsert:true})
```

What this does is, is always keeps the size of the `records` array to `50` and always sorts the records whenever new sub documents are inserted at a `level`.

A simple find, `db.collection.find({"level":{$in:[1,2,..]}})`, would give you the top 50 records in order, for each selected `level`.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. In essence, I would be "pre-sorting" the data on the way in (ie, "insert this record at level x, then do the sorting / slicing as necessary")? What if I have a bunch of records already (~20k spread across ~100 levels), is there an easy way to just pull them in? Additionally, if this isn't super urgent, could I just wait until that issue with `$slice` gets taken care of? What would it look like in that case, if you don't mind?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. The update operators: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/, were introduced for this very purpose in 2.4. In case you already have a lot of records, you could migrate them to your new document structure using map-reduce. It will be simple and straight forward, but you need to make a lot of changes to your existing application code, refactor the queries. Having said this, if you have just started writing your application code, you could go for this approach.  The JIRA ticked has been open now for around two and a half years.

Comment: Am Skeptical about it being fixed soon. In case you opt to stay with your current document structure, you need to perform the slicing in the client side, Or fire multiple queries for each level, remember - you will definitely have to fire atleast a single query for each level. That makes it more worse.

Comment: Of course, that's as expected given the date -- I didn't notice the issue post date originally. Well, I have a while to wait before I will need to go down the avenue of wiping my games data for this leaderboard, so I'll re-evaluate at that time. For now, I'll accept this answer given that it is thought out and is correct, despite requiring changes to the structure. Thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome, and please do update if find a different approach.

Comment: FYI, a better Jira issue to upvote/watch is [SERVER-9377: Extend $push or $max to allow collecting "top" N values per _id key in $group phase](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377).

Comment: @BatScream: You might also want to remove/caveat the mention of `$slice` for aggregation. Ideally top-n should be an accumulator so the only the n-highest results (according to a defined sort order) are saved. A `$slice` would only work if you calculate the whole result set and then throw out all the results you don't want. Pushing to a capped array is a good workaround in the interim ;-).

Comment: @Stennie, yes that makes perfect sense. I removed the reference to the `$slice` operator. Thanks once again for your valuable comments.